# Which photos to be transferred after backup in a new apple device?

Tags: icloud, photo-stream

If I open my iCloud account in a new apple device, then which photos would be transferred - photos from camera roll or photostream ?

Answer (score 1):

Signing in to a new device with your iCloud account will give you access to your Photo Stream. Setting up a new device with your iCloud account and selecting to restore from an iCloud Backup will restore the Camera Roll as well.

Comment: So you mean at the beginning, only photostream photos will be transferred immediately after I log in with my iCloud and it's our wish to give access to camera roll pics ?? So is it safe for me to delete pics from camera roll pr photostream for making a space in storage ? Because all camera roll pics are same as photostream. Right?